# showing squares instead of folder name characters while saving in attachment in bluemail

Tags: fonts, email-client

Because of the beautiful design, I prefer to use Bluemail as my email client, everything is fine and working, but when I want to save an attachment to my folders, it shows meaningless squares instead of showing the folder name characters. (as in the picture attached)
is there anyway to solve it?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and I am not sure what other information I must add

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete the font cache of the application:

```
rm -rf ~/snap/bluemail/common/.cache/fontconfig/
```

If that does not solve the issue, also refresh your font cache:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/fontconfig
fc-cache -r -v
```

Comment: Refreshing my font cache (your second recommended step) solved the problem. Thank you very much